Detecting Weight Number on Weight Scale Image using OCR
I am in the process of developing an OCR-Based Weight Measurement System for my project
Here are my Colab Notebook for my complete code
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jUIW5SAvNJdJE-Zx2Qu9yzTOtgqdwb_K?usp=sharing
I have a dataset comprising weight scale images that require recognition, consisting of two distinct types of weight scales.Here are the sample images


I am detailing the steps I am taking to extract the weight result using OCR:

Getting the Weight Segment:


Objective: Extract the portion of the image containing the weight information, excluding other details.
Method: Remove the lower part with unit price and total price, focusing solely on the weight.
Code:

`def get_weight_segment(image, upper_cut_percentage=0.5, left_cut_percentage=0):   height, width, _ = image.shape   upper_segment_height = int(height * upper_cut_percentage)
#Calculate the width after cutting 20% from the left   cut_width = int(width * left_cut_percentage)   upper_segment_width = width - cut_width
#Extract the upper segment of the image with left cut   upper_segment = image[:upper_segment_height, cut_width:]
return upper_segment`

Image Result:




Image Normalization


Objective: Normalize the image to enhance its quality for further processing.
Method: Normalize the image to a standard scale using OpenCV.
Code:

def normalization(image): norm_img = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1])) img = cv2.normalize(image, norm_img, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) return img

Image result:




Get Red Region


Objective: Isolate the red regions within the image, typically representing the weight digits.
Method: Utilize HSV color space to identify red regions and extract them.
Code:

`def get_red_region(image, padding_ratio=0.1):
RED_MIN1 = np.array([0, 50, 50], np.uint8)
RED_MAX1 = np.array([40, 255, 255], np.uint8)
RED_MIN2 = np.array([150, 50, 50], np.uint8)
RED_MAX2 = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

frame_threshed1 = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, RED_MIN1, RED_MAX1)
frame_threshed2 = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, RED_MIN2, RED_MAX2)

combined_threshed = cv2.bitwise_or(frame_threshed1, frame_threshed2)

#Set non-red regions to white
result_image = np.ones_like(image, dtype=np.uint8) * 255  # Initialize with white color
result_image[combined_threshed != 0] = image[combined_threshed != 0]

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(combined_threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

if contours:
    largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    # Get the bounding box of the largest contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_contour)
    # Calculate padding based on the bounding box dimensions
    padding_x = int(w * padding_ratio)
    padding_y = int(h * padding_ratio)
    # Add padding to the bounding box
    x -= padding_x
    y -= padding_y
    w += 2 * padding_x
    h += 2 * padding_y
    # Ensure the bounding box stays within image bounds
    x = max(x, 0)
    y = max(y, 0)
    w = min(w, result_image.shape[1] - x)
    h = min(h, result_image.shape[0] - y)
    # Crop the input image using the adjusted bounding box
    cropped_image = result_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Apply erosion and dilation to the cropped image
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    cropped_image = cv2.erode(cropped_image, kernel, iterations=1)
    cropped_image = cv2.dilate(cropped_image, kernel, iterations=1)

    return cropped_image
else:
    return result_image  # Return the masked image if no contour found`


Result




Grayscalling


Objective: Convert the image to grayscale and place it at the center of a blank canvas.
Method: Convert the image to grayscale and embed it in a blank canvas.
Code:

`def grayscalling(image):
#Convert the image to grayscale
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#Determine the dimensions of the canvas
canvas_size = 1000
padding_ratio = 0.3

#Calculate the target size for the image
target_size = canvas_size - int(canvas_size * padding_ratio * 2)

#Determine the scaling factor based on the smaller dimension
scaling_factor = min(target_size / gray_image.shape[0], target_size / gray_image.shape[1])

#Resize the image to fit the canvas while preserving the aspect ratio
resized_gray_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, (int(gray_image.shape[1] * scaling_factor), int(gray_image.shape[0] * scaling_factor)))

#Create the canvas
canvas = np.ones((canvas_size, canvas_size), dtype=np.uint8) * 255  # Initialize with white color

#Calculate the coordinates to place the image in the center
y_offset = (canvas.shape[0] - resized_gray_image.shape[0]) // 2
x_offset = (canvas.shape[1] - resized_gray_image.shape[1]) // 2

#Paste the resized grayscale image onto the canvas
canvas[y_offset:y_offset + resized_gray_image.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset + resized_gray_image.shape[1]] = resized_gray_image

return canvas`


ImageResult:




Read Text From Image


Objective: Utilize EasyOCR to extract the weight number from the image segment.
Method: Employ EasyOCR library to read text from the image.
Code:

`def read_text_from_image(image):
#Initialize the EasyOCR reader
reader = Reader(['en'])
#Read text from the image
results = reader.readtext(image)

#Display the results
bbox, text, prob = results[0]
weight = text[:-2] + '.' + text[-2:]
print(f'Berat Sayuran Adalah : {weight} KG')`

Despite my efforts, I'm encountering subpar results with my dataset, with approximately 40% of predictions being incorrect. Here are examples:


However, around 60% of the images are predicted correctly. Upon analysis, I deduce that my image preprocessing methods before feeding them into EasyOCR may require refinement. Specifically, the following processes could benefit from improvement:

Red Number Extraction: Enhancing the method for isolating red numbers in the image.
Conversion to Grayscale: Improving the conversion of red numbers to grayscale; previous attempts with Otsu thresholding yielded unsatisfactory results.
OCR Model Selection: Exploring alternative open-source OCR models that may outperform EasyOCR for this specific task.

I welcome recommendations for refining or augmenting my preprocessing steps. Feel free to access my Google Colab notebook and clone it. The dataset is available in my public GitHub repository, accessible via the Colab notebook.
